# D3.js transition not working as intended

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg, transition

I have 2 arrays with different objects like {x1: 10, x2: 20, y1: 10, y2: 20} which are coordinates for lines, I want a SVG to transition from my first array to the second, however it "kind" of does it, but in the end it doesn't look as my final array.

```
if($percentageComplete<=25&&$percentageComplete>00)
  {
    var index =0;
var index2=0;
circle.data(projectMt).transition()
 .attr("y1", function (d) {
  var actual = mainMt[i].y1;
  var cambio = d.y1;
  //console.log("Y1 "+mainMt[index].y1)
  //console.log("Actual: "+actual);
  //console.log("Cambio: "+cambio);
  index++;
  //console.log("Y1 ACTUANDO");
  //console.log(actual-(cambio*$percentageComplete)/25);
  return (cambio);

})
  .attr("y2", function (d) {
  var actual = mainMt[i].y2;
  var cambio = d.y2;
  //console.log("Y2 "+mainMt[index2].y2)
  //console.log("Actual: "+actual);
  //console.log("Cambio: "+cambio);
  index2++;
  //console.log("Y2 ACTUANDO");
  //console.log(actual-(cambio*$percentageComplete)/25);
  return (cambio);

});
  console.log(index+""+index2);
 }
```

My first array is mainMt, my second array is projectMt, we only need the y's to change, the x are not important. The result is a figure which kinda looks as it's supposed to, but doesn't entirely.

Here's the full code of that :
http://www.carshel.com/tramonte/

Edit: Scroll to see the transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you data produces im afraid. Here is a fiddle just editing the `y` coordinates : https://jsfiddle.net/wasd3k5e/2/

And both the `x` and the `y` coordinates : https://jsfiddle.net/wasd3k5e/1/

So even though it doesn't look nice, it's because you're only updating the `y` coordinates. It's what your data shows.

I edited out your transition and just added this :

```
circle.transition(500)
     //.attr('x1',function(d,i){ return projectMt[i].x1})
     .attr('y1',function(d,i){ return projectMt[i].y1})
     //.attr('x2',function(d,i){ return projectMt[i].x2})
     .attr('y2',function(d,i){ return projectMt[i].y2})
```

Works similar way :)